# How to use php with img scr html tag?

Tags: php, html

So depending on the variable `$movie = $_REQUEST["film"];` the img scr path will change accordingly, since the variable `$movie` will indicate the folder name. 
So `<img src=<?php $movie"/"?>overview.png" ...>` doesn't work for me. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Share more code and error if any ?

Comment: `<?php $movie"/"?>` won't work for at least two reasons: You need to concat the strings, `$movie."/"` (the dot makes the difference), and you don't actually print/echo it there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the directory is declared like so:

```
$movie = '/assets/img/movies/the-matrix';
```

.. then you need to include that tag in the HTML:

```
<img src="<? echo $movie; ?>/overview.png">
```

or even shorter:

```
<img src="<?=$movie;?>/overview.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to echo the movie variable in your img src.
Until

you can try this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $movies; ?>/overview.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a big load of php on that page and dont want to write it out  all of the time, you can have it display anyway, eg

```
<php 
    /*Lots of other code*/
    echo "<img src='$movie/overview.png' />";
    /*Lots of other code*/
?>
```

I am currently using the above code in many of my pages without any issues. Because i use data bases so often and so much in my code, i find it easier to have html code within the